# C++ meta-programming with "invalid" template parameters - is it permitted?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

In some of my code where I use meta-programming techniques, we use templated arguments that get forwarded elsewhere and later converted, so we never actually create instances of some of these classes.

In particular, we use `std::vector<T>` where T does not have the semantics to be included in a vector. In reality though we create a `std::vector<shared_ptr<T> >`.

The code looks a bit like this:

```
class Bar : noncopyable
{ 
    // whatever
};

class Foo : public FooInterface
{
  public:
    explicit Foo( std::vector< shared_ptr<Bar> > );
};

typedef Builder1Param< FooInterface, Foo, std::vector<Bar> > FooBuilder;
```

through clever meta-programming techniques, FooBuilder knows that it will pass in a `vector<shared_ptr<Bar> >` to `Foo` and not a `vector<Bar>`. The issue is that because Bar is non-copyable it is an invalid type for a vector.

Now the code compiles fine on any compiler that I have used this, but I would like to know if it is valid C++ (and will continue to be so into C++11 and beyond).

I should possibly add that Bar may actually be abstract (and often will be). The purpose is to indicate that the parameter is a collection of these (in a sense in the style of Java/C# references).

Comment: I think the requirements on `T` are all phrased as requirements in order to use particular expressions involving the container. So for example assigning the container requires that `T` is `CopyAssignable`, but you can have containers of types that are not copyable (and the container might even be useful if the type is movable despite not being copyable). But I'm not sure that all requirements on `T` are expressed in this way, so I'm not absolutely certain.

Comment: I know concepts were never actually brought into C++. The main question is whether concepts would be enforced on template parameters even if you never try to create an instance of one, or use one in regular code as a pointer/reference. That is, given that Builder1Param is my own template and therefore knows what to do with its parameters.

Comment: well, it would be most peculiar (and break existing C++11 code) if a future standard were to enforce that vector elements were Copyable in the case where you don't use any expressions that actually need that. Aside from anything else it would forbid `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`. But that's just Copyable, I can't swear to you that no standard will ever enforce some weaker concept at the point where you mention `vector<T>` rather than the point where you actually use it to do something that depends on properties of the type `T`.

Comment: I have considered whether, to be safe, I should define my own Vector and Map templates for this purpose. Of course I won't be rewriting vector and map... these templates would at most have a few typedefs in them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't instantiate the type you're fine *technically*, same as with e.g. incomplete type.

However, it's a horrible design.

All that contortion in order make it possible to use more keypresses to write something misleading instead of just passing parameters.

I would reconsider that design.

E.g. do

```
typedef Builder1Param< FooInterface, Foo, std::vector, Bar > FooBuilder;
```

For the template definition part, `std::vector` is here a template template parameter.

Comment: Builder1Param requires 3 template parameters so that won't work. It's also more confusing than what I have done.

And it's not intended to save keystrokes, more to hide the "noise" of shared_ptr which is an implementation detail, because really it is a collection of Bar objects, not a collection of shared pointers, we just use shared_ptr has a sort-of adapter to let them go in a vector.

Of I am hoping one day to make the templates variadic.

Comment: @CashCow: change Builder1Param, or make your own.

Comment: It is my own... The first is the interface, the second is the class you are building and the remainder represent the parameters you use to construct / build it. In a builder design pattern, you have to build its components too. Foo takes 1 parameter.

Comment: @CashCow: also, forget about "pattern". do what's practical. the solution to "must have one parameter at the end" is not to have one actual parameter that you then with intricate code massage into something else. the solution is to have one parameter at the end, and the most practical parameters at the outset (whatever is practical for you, e.g. you could collect types into one thing if you want, but `std::vector` is not a good vehicle for that). i.e., again, do what's practical, forget about ideals when they don't work good.

Comment: It works the way it is now. I was just asking if it was technically legal according to the standard or whether I am just lucky with compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::vector<Bar>` in a program where `Bar` does not meet the requirements for `std::vector` produces undefined behaviour. This is from 17.6.4.8 [res.on.functions] in the C++11 Standard:

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C ++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C ++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> — for types used as template arguments when instantiating a template component, if the operations on the type do not implement the semantics of the applicable Requirements subclause (17.6.3.5, 23.2, 24.2, 26.2).
>
> ...
>
> — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Comment: you failed to notice the word "instantiating" in the standardese?

Comment: No, I just felt that it was too fine a line. 14.7.1p5: " A class template specialization is implicitly instantiated if the class type is used in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or if the completeness of the class type might affect the semantics of the program." and 14.7.1p6: "If the overload resolution process can determine the correct function to call without instantiating a class template definition, it is unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place." It is very easy to accidentally trigger implicit instantiation, and thus undefined behaviour.

Comment: Presumably in my case it would be "undefined compiler behaviour" i.e. it can choose to let it compile or not. The normal "undefined behaviour" is runtime but obviously I'm talking about a case where it would definitely fail to compile if you tried to instantiate one.